# Cropping image in android without using the crop intent

Tags: android, crop

I am trying to develop a small cropping application. I will be using a overlay on the camera window like we normally have in bar code scanners. But I want to crop the overlay part of the image after user clicks a pic and just store the non-overlay part. I tried the native cropping functionality but it tells the user to select the cropping part. I want to directly crop the photo and save it in the gallery. How can I achieve this??

Now I am using the following code for cropping....

```
private void performCrop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
            //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent,AppUtils.PIC_CROP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `Bitmap` instance with the original image. In that case, just use [`Bitmap.createBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to select the area you need.

```
Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, left, top, width, height);
```